# modify date after selection at Calendar component (datetime datatype)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Assuming that i picked a day from a Calendar component on VS 2008, how may i add a specific number of days to the date? (i've to store the final date in datetime datatype to DB after which) Parsing involved possibly? May I have a sample on how it is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Dim tempDate As DateTime

    tempDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(5)
```